# How do I check if a char is equal to a hyphen or a character?

Tags: java, string, stack, character

I am trying to remove any underscores or hyphens in my text & any letter that precedes an underscore or hyphen should be capatalized.

My code takes a string parameter & converts the string into an array of characters that are inserted into a stack. I then use a while loop that pops a character from the stack & uses an if statement. The if statement checks if the character is not an underscore or a hyphen to then append it to the string variable `word`. But if it is a hyphen or an underscore then capitalize the first letter of `word` as that is the last appended character & the underscore or hyphen is not appended.

However, the underscores & hyphens still remain in the string I have checked & found the issue. For some reason underscores & hyphens pass the if statement `if(character != underscore || character != hyphen)` I don't understand why when `character` is a hyphen or underscore it does not equal to either the char variables `underscore` or `hyphen`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Stack;

 class Solution{

 static String toCamelCase(String s){
   
  Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
  String word = null;
  char underscore = '_';
  char hyphen = '-';
 
  char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

  for(char character : charArray){
  
   stack.push(character);
  }

  while(!stack.empty()){
  
   char character = stack.pop();
  
   if(character != underscore || character != hyphen){
          
     if(word == null){
      
      word = String.valueOf(character);
     }else{
      
      word = character + word;
     }
   }else{
    
     if(word != null){
      
      char[] wordToCharArray = word.toCharArray();
      char firstLetter = Character.toUpperCase(wordToCharArray[0]);
      wordToCharArray[0] = firstLetter;
      word = String.valueOf(wordToCharArray);
     }
   }
 }

 return word;
}
}
```

Comment: Please work out a simple truth table for your || condition that you don't understand why it's failing.

Comment: Looks like a job for regular expressions!

Comment: The attempt to code this for yourself is commendable (and understandable if this is a class assignment), but nowadays most would just use a standard library class like Apache Commons CaseUtils.

Comment: @DavidDenenberg I don't understand what you mean by a simple truth table, is the issue with the conditional statement in the if statement?

Comment: @kshetline am I not using regular expressions?

Comment: @ZahidHabib, Java regular expressions:https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you have.

```
if(character != underscore || character != hyphen) {
```

Using one of [De Morgans laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), where
`( a || b)` is the same as `!(!a && !b)`

it can be rewritten as:

```
if (!(character == underscore && character == hyphen)) {
```

Now, looking at the inner comparison, can a single char variable be two different things at the same time?  Since the condition will always be `false`, the `!` changes it to `true`, so it will always be `true`, just like your original expression.  This is because if one of your original comparisons is false, the the other must be true.  And since it is using an OR it will always be true.

So change your `||` to `&&`

Comment: But this does not fix the issue, why does my if statement still allows hyphens & underscores when the expression is meant to not allow it?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to check if there is a hyphen or underscore in the text as you asked, but there's a problem with it, there's a ton of nesting, and some of the code is in the wrong place therefore it won't execute your if statement which has nothing in it, I will re-write you're code and you can paste it into your file and hope that it works (which i'm sure it will.)

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Stack;

 class Solution{

 static String toCamelCase(String s){
   
  Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
  String word = null;
  char underscore = '_';
  char hyphen = '-';
 
  char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

  for(char character : charArray){
  
   stack.push(character);
  }

  while(!stack.empty()){
  
   char character = stack.pop();
  
   if(character == underscore || character == hyphen){
       // Here we're defining the underscore and hyphen
       // So you can remove them if they are there.
       // Make sure next time that you aren't using the not logical
       // Operator when you are checking if the word has it or not rather than
       // It not having it or not, and also add two equals next time to compare
       // Variables to eachother
       underscore = '_';
       hyphen = '-'; 
    character.remove(underscore || hyphen)
     if(word == null){
      word = String.valueOf(character);
     } else {
      word = character + word;
     }
   } else {
    
     if(word != null){
      
      char[] wordToCharArray = word.toCharArray();
      char firstLetter = Character.toUpperCase(wordToCharArray[0]);
      wordToCharArray[0] = firstLetter;
      word = String.valueOf(wordToCharArray);
     }
   }
 }

 return word;
}
}
```

Tips for the future: if your trying to compare a variable (in this case hyphens and underscores) make sure to use the double equal sign: (==) rather than the equal sign: (=) as that is declaring a variable rather than comparing it. And if you can, I'd suggest watching youtube tutorials on how to remove nestings from code i.e Java.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to change the condition:

```java
if (character != underscore && character != hyphen)
    // do smth.
else if(word != null)
    // do smth.
```

---

I think you could reformat your code and simplify the logic:

```java
public static String toCamelCase(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    boolean upperCase = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (ch == '-' || ch == '_')
            upperCase = true;
        else {
            buf.append(upperCase ? Character.toUpperCase(ch) : ch);
            upperCase = false;
        }
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 9 (or later) and regular expressions, you can make it as simple as this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Playground {
    static Pattern kebobPattern = Pattern.compile("[-_][a-z]");

    public static String toCamelCase(String s) {
        return kebobPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll(m -> m.group().substring(1).toUpperCase());
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        System.out.println(toCamelCase("sample-string-with_punctuation"));
        System.out.println(toCamelCase("another_sample-foo_bar-baz"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sampleStringWithPunctuation
anotherSampleFooBarBaz
```

Please note that this code wouldn't get rid of all dashes and underscores. I simplified this for the specific goal of converting kebab case to camel case, so only dashes or underscores followed by lowercase letters are replaced. You can tweak this as necessary for more/different functionality.